# exception when selecting image from gallery

Tags: android

I am trying to browse an image from the gallery. But I get the following runtime exception

> 04-24 08:00:11.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1546): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   04-24 08:00:11.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1546): Process: com.dropbox.android.sample, PID: 1546
>   04-24 08:00:11.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1546): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/125 }} to activity {com.dropbox.android.sample/com.dropbox.android.sample.DBRoulette}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   04-24 08:00:11.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1546):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3365)
>   04-24 08:00:11.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1546):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3408)
>   04-24 08:00:11.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1546):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
>   04-24 08:00:11.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1546):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
>   04-24 08:00:11.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1546):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   04-24 08:00:11.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1546):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>   04-24 08:00:11.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1546):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>   04-24 08:00:11.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1546):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   04-24 08:00:11.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1546):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   04-24 08:00:11.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1546):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   04-24 08:00:11.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1546):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>   04-24 08:00:11.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1546):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   04-24 08:00:11.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1546): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   04-24 08:00:11.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1546):     at java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:185)
>   04-24 08:00:11.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1546):     at java.io.File.(File.java:134)
>   04-24 08:00:11.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1546):     at com.dropbox.android.sample.DBRoulette.onActivityResult(DBRoulette.java:298)
>   04-24 08:00:11.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1546):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
>   04-24 08:00:11.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1546):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3361)
>   04-24 08:00:11.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1546):     ... 11 more

The code is

```
package com.dropbox.android.sample;

import java.io.File;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI;
import com.dropbox.client2.android.AndroidAuthSession;
import com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity;
import com.dropbox.client2.session.AccessTokenPair;
import com.dropbox.client2.session.AppKeyPair;


public class DBRoulette extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "DBRoulette";

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //                      Your app-specific settings.                      //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Replace this with your app key and secret assigned by Dropbox.
    // Note that this is a really insecure way to do this, and you shouldn't
    // ship code which contains your key & secret in such an obvious way.
    // Obfuscation is good.
    final static private String APP_KEY = "s9go8rgx96d0nsx";
    final static private String APP_SECRET = "424tdfp223r29is";

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //                      End app-specific settings.                       //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;

    // directory name to store captured images and videos
    private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "Hello Camera";

    private Uri fileUri; // file url to store image/video

    static String imagePath;






    // You don't need to change these, leave them alone.
    final static private String ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME = "prefs";
    final static private String ACCESS_KEY_NAME = "ACCESS_KEY";
    final static private String ACCESS_SECRET_NAME = "ACCESS_SECRET";

    private static final boolean USE_OAUTH1 = false;

    DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> mApi;

    private boolean mLoggedIn;
    private File file;
    // Android widgets
    private Button mSubmit;
    private LinearLayout mDisplay;
    private Button mPhoto;
    private Button mRoulette;
    private Button btnBrowse;
    private ImageView mImage;
    Handler hand = new Handler();
    private final String PHOTO_DIR = "/Photos/";

    final static private int NEW_PICTURE = 1;
    final static private int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;

    protected static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;


    private String mCameraFileName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCameraFileName = savedInstanceState.getString("mCameraFileName");
        }

        // We create a new AuthSession so that we can use the Dropbox API.
        AndroidAuthSession session = buildSession();
        mApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);

        // Basic Android widgets
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        checkAppKeySetup();

        mSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.auth_button);

        mSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // This logs you out if you're logged in, or vice versa
                if (mLoggedIn) {
                    logOut();
                } else {
                    // Start the remote authentication
                    if (USE_OAUTH1) {
                        mApi.getSession().startAuthentication(DBRoulette.this);
                    } else {
                        mApi.getSession().startOAuth2Authentication(DBRoulette.this);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        mDisplay = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.logged_in_display);

        // This is where a photo is displayed
        mImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view);

        // This is the button to take a photo
        mPhoto = (Button)findViewById(R.id.photo_button);

        btnBrowse = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBrowse);

        mPhoto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();

                intent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                // MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI isn't working right.

                Date date = new Date();
                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-kk-mm-ss");

                String newPicFile = "Input" + df.format(date) + ".jpg";
                String outPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), newPicFile).getPath();
                File outFile = new File(outPath);

                mCameraFileName = outFile.toString();
                Uri outuri = Uri.fromFile(outFile);

                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outuri);
                Log.i(TAG, "Importing New Picture: " + mCameraFileName);
                try {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, NEW_PICTURE);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    showToast("There doesn't seem to be a camera.");
                }


                /*Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

                // start the image capture Intent
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);*/


            }

        });



        btnBrowse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()     //remove this
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

            }
        });


        // This is the button to take a photo
        /*mRoulette = (Button)findViewById(R.id.roulette_button);

        mRoulette.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //DownloadRandomPicture download = new DownloadRandomPicture(DBRoulette.this, mApi, PHOTO_DIR, mImage);
                //download.execute();
            }
        });*/

        // Display the proper UI state if logged in or not
        setLoggedIn(mApi.getSession().isLinked());

    }











    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putString("mCameraFileName", mCameraFileName);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        AndroidAuthSession session = mApi.getSession();

        // The next part must be inserted in the onResume() method of the
        // activity from which session.startAuthentication() was called, so
        // that Dropbox authentication completes properly.
        if (session.authenticationSuccessful()) {
            try {
                // Mandatory call to complete the auth
                session.finishAuthentication();

                // Store it locally in our app for later use
                storeAuth(session);
                setLoggedIn(true);
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                showToast("Couldn't authenticate with Dropbox:" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                Log.i(TAG, "Error authenticating", e);
            }
        }
    }

    // This is what gets called on finishing a media piece to import
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == NEW_PICTURE) {
            // return from file upload
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                //Uri uri = null;
                //if (data != null) {
                //  uri = data.getData();
                //}
                //if (uri == null && mCameraFileName != null) {
                //  uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(mCameraFileName));
                //}
                //file = new File(mCameraFileName);

                file = new File(mCameraFileName);
                //if (uri != null) {


                    UploadPicture upload = new UploadPicture(this, mApi, PHOTO_DIR, file, mImage);
                    upload.execute();




                //}
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "Unknown Activity Result from mediaImport: "
                        + resultCode);
            }
        }
         if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);



            //the path where the image is located is stored in string variable

            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);         
            cursor.close();
            mImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
            //Displaying the selected image in the image view. 




            //Displaying the path of the selected image
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            /*File file2 = new File(picturePath);
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri uri = null;
                if (data != null) {
                    uri = data.getData();
                }
                if (uri == null && picturePath != null) {
                    uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(picturePath));
                }


                if (uri != null) {
                    UploadPicture upload = new UploadPicture(this, mApi, PHOTO_DIR, file2, mImage);
                    upload.execute();
                }
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "Unknown Activity Result from mediaImport: "
                        + resultCode);


            }*/
        }
    }



    private void logOut() {
        // Remove credentials from the session
        mApi.getSession().unlink();

        // Clear our stored keys
        clearKeys();
        // Change UI state to display logged out version
        setLoggedIn(false);
    }

    /**
     * Convenience function to change UI state based on being logged in
     */
    private void setLoggedIn(boolean loggedIn) {
        mLoggedIn = loggedIn;
        if (loggedIn) {
            mSubmit.setText("Unlink from Dropbox");
            mDisplay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            mSubmit.setText("Link with Dropbox");
            mDisplay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mImage.setImageDrawable(null);
        }
    }

    private void checkAppKeySetup() {
        // Check to make sure that we have a valid app key
        if (APP_KEY.startsWith("CHANGE") ||
                APP_SECRET.startsWith("CHANGE")) {
            showToast("You must apply for an app key and secret from developers.dropbox.com, and add them to the DBRoulette ap before trying it.");
            finish();
            return;
        }

        // Check if the app has set up its manifest properly.
        Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        String scheme = "db-" + APP_KEY;
        String uri = scheme + "://" + AuthActivity.AUTH_VERSION + "/test";
        testIntent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        if (0 == pm.queryIntentActivities(testIntent, 0).size()) {
            showToast("URL scheme in your app's " +
                    "manifest is not set up correctly. You should have a " +
                    "com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity with the " +
                    "scheme: " + scheme);
            finish();
        }
    }

    private void showToast(String msg) {
        Toast error = Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        error.show();
    }

    /**
     * Shows keeping the access keys returned from Trusted Authenticator in a local
     * store, rather than storing user name & password, and re-authenticating each
     * time (which is not to be done, ever).
     */
    private void loadAuth(AndroidAuthSession session) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
        String key = prefs.getString(ACCESS_KEY_NAME, null);
        String secret = prefs.getString(ACCESS_SECRET_NAME, null);
        if (key == null || secret == null || key.length() == 0 || secret.length() == 0) return;

        if (key.equals("oauth2:")) {
            // If the key is set to "oauth2:", then we can assume the token is for OAuth 2.
            session.setOAuth2AccessToken(secret);
        } else {
            // Still support using old OAuth 1 tokens.
            session.setAccessTokenPair(new AccessTokenPair(key, secret));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Shows keeping the access keys returned from Trusted Authenticator in a local
     * store, rather than storing user name & password, and re-authenticating each
     * time (which is not to be done, ever).
     */
    private void storeAuth(AndroidAuthSession session) {
        // Store the OAuth 2 access token, if there is one.
        String oauth2AccessToken = session.getOAuth2AccessToken();
        if (oauth2AccessToken != null) {
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
            Editor edit = prefs.edit();
            edit.putString(ACCESS_KEY_NAME, "oauth2:");
            edit.putString(ACCESS_SECRET_NAME, oauth2AccessToken);
            edit.commit();
            return;
        }
        // Store the OAuth 1 access token, if there is one.  This is only necessary if
        // you're still using OAuth 1.
        AccessTokenPair oauth1AccessToken = session.getAccessTokenPair();
        if (oauth1AccessToken != null) {
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
            Editor edit = prefs.edit();
            edit.putString(ACCESS_KEY_NAME, oauth1AccessToken.key);
            edit.putString(ACCESS_SECRET_NAME, oauth1AccessToken.secret);
            edit.commit();
            return;
        }
    }

    private void clearKeys() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
        Editor edit = prefs.edit();
        edit.clear();
        edit.commit();
    }

    private AndroidAuthSession buildSession() {
        AppKeyPair appKeyPair = new AppKeyPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);

        AndroidAuthSession session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeyPair);
        loadAuth(session);
        return session;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

File path in DBRoulette.java:298 is null. See: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robovm/robovm-rt/0.0.2/java/io/File.java#185

Comment: I don't know your code. You have to check, why mCameraFileName is null and fix it.

Comment: The exception occurs when I try to browse gallery. mCameraFileName doesn't appear in that segment at all. It is used when I am clicking a picture and it works perfectly then. I have given the code as REQUEST_LOAD_IMAGE for the gallery intent. So it goes to the else part.

Comment: I have posted the entire code. Somebody please tell me why my application crashes when I try to browse a picture from the gallery